# How do I print every object in an arraylist and correctly count their quantity?

Tags: java, arraylist, tostring

I have a class which takes an arraylist of items determined by their name, price and quantity and is supposed to print each unique item and increase quantity accordingly if more than one of the same item are added to the arraylist.

I have 2 problems with my current code: Firstly, It only prints the last item in the arraylist. Secondly, it returns an incorrect quantity for the printed item.

```
package shop;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ShoppingCart {
static ArrayList<Product> cart;

    public ShoppingCart() {
        ShoppingCart.cart = new ArrayList<Product>();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat ("#.00");
        int quantity = 0;
        double price = 0;
        String name = null;
        double total = 0;
        for (Product p: cart) {
            quantity = p.getQuantity();
            price = p.getPrice();
            name = p.getName();
            total = p.getTotalPrice();  
        }
        return quantity + " * GBP    " + format.format(price) + " " + name            + "    = GBP   " + format.format(total);  
    }
    public void add(Product p) {
            if(cart.size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < cart.size(); i++) {
                    if(cart.get(i).getName().equals(p.getName()) 
                    && cart.get(i).getPrice() == p.getPrice()) {

                        cart.get(i).setQuantity(cart.get(i).getQuantity() + p.getQuantity());

                    }else {
                        cart.add(p);
                    }
                }
            }else {
            cart.add(p);
        }
    }   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ShoppingCart newCart = new ShoppingCart();

        Product apple, apples, milk, caulk, ice, snakes;
        apple = new Product("Apples (4 pack)", 1.20, 1);
        apples = new Product("Apples (4 pack)", 1.20, 2);
        milk = new Product("Milk (1l)", 0.75, 1);
        caulk = new Product("Caulk (1l)", 6.84, 1);
        ice = new Product("Ice (1kg)", 4.30, 1);
        snakes = new Product("Snake (5m)", 32.0, 1);

        newCart.add(apple);
        newCart.add(apple);
        newCart.add(apple);
        newCart.add(apple);
        newCart.add(caulk);
        newCart.add(milk);


        System.out.println(newCart);


    }
}
```

The output is

```
4 * GBP    .75 Milk (1l)    = GBP   3.00
```

I'm guessing something has gone wrong in my `toString()` and `add()` methods, but I can't tell what.

Comment: I don't know what's the format of your output should be, I just tried to find your problem and tell how you can solve that. Please make it better to what you want

Comment: As a total aside — you should (nearly always) _declare_ using the interface List, like `List<Product> cart;` then pick the implementation when you _create_ the actual list `ShoppingCart.cart = new ArrayList<>();` (and use the "diamond" operator `<>` - you don't have to repeat the type "Product")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to implement `Product.toString()` as follow for example :

   ```
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
       return String.format("%d * GBP %5s %15s= GBP %5s", quantity, format.format(price), 
                                                   name, format.format(price * quantity));

   }
   ```
2. And the `ShoppingCart.toString()` will use `Product.toString()` of each `Product` :

   ```
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       double total = 0;
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       for (Product p : cart) {
           sb.append(p.toString()).append("\n");
           total += p.getTotalPrice();
       }
       sb.append(String.format("%s%33.2f", "Total :", total));
       return sb.toString();
   }
   ```
3. Finally you'll get :

   ```
   8 * GBP  1,20 Apples (4 pack)= GBP  9,60
   2 * GBP  6,84      Caulk (1l)= GBP 13,68
   4 * GBP   ,75       Milk (1l)= GBP  3,00
   4 * GBP   ,75       Milk (1l)= GBP  3,00
   Total :                            29,28
   ```

As now, when you set a new `quantity` it affects the initial object as it's referenced in the list, you need to add a copy of in the list, also change the loop : when you find the same product, change the quantity then return, and **only at the end of the loop* if you haven't find the product you'll add it, you need to wait to check all the existant products :

```
public void add(Product p) {
    if (cart.size() > 0) {
        for (Product product : cart) {
            if (product.getName().equals(p.getName()) && product.getPrice() == p.getPrice()) {
                product.setQuantity(product.getQuantity() + p.getQuantity());
                return;
            }
        }
        cart.add(new Product(p));
    } else {
        cart.add(new Product(p));
    }
}
```

And in `Product` class, a copy constructor :

```
public Product(Product p) {
    this.quantity = p.quantity;
    this.price = p.price;
    this.name = p.name;
}
```

---

Also, don't make the list static, each shoppingCart has its own list

```
private ArrayList<Product> cart;

public ShoppingCart() {
    cart = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my problem with the printing, but the quantity is still double what it should be, and I have no idea why Milk shows up twice. This also happened before I made a toString() method and was testing with a println() in main

Comment: @kotsoteka this is because you are changing the properties of the object itself, so after put apple twice its quantity will be 2 in the object, I'll write something to fix this

Comment: @kotsoteka done, I used a foreach loop to avoid the access by index, it's more readable

Answer (score 0):

In `toString()` method you have a for loop but you are just keeping last item data in the loop. you should correct it like this:

```
   String name = "";
   for (Product p: cart) {
        quantity += p.getQuantity();
        price += p.getPrice();
        name += p.getName();
        total += p.getTotalPrice();  
    }
```